# Typeorm eager load with a condition for the children

Tags: typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I have two entities, one parent and one child. There is a OneToMany relation with eager enabled.

When I get the parent entity I would like to load only children with the property `deleted` to `false`. For now it's returning all children.

Here are my files:

```js
@Entity()
export class Parent {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ default: false })
  deleted: boolean;

  @OneToMany(() => Child, (child) => child.parent, {
    cascade: true,
    eager: true,
  })
  children: Child[];
}
```

```js
@Entity()
export class Child{
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ default: false })
  deleted: boolean;

  @ManyToOne(() => Parent, (parent) => parent.children)
  parent: Parent;
}
```

```js
@Injectable()
export class ParentsService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Parent)
    private parentRepository: Repository<Parent>,
  ) {}

  findAll(): Promise<Parent[]> {
    return this.parentRepository.find({ where: { deleted: false } });
  }
}
```

I tried to change my findAll like this, but then if my parent as one child deleted, the parent wont be retrieved :

```js
  findAll(): Promise<Parent[]> {
    return this.parentRepository.find({ where: { deleted: false, children:{deleted:false} } });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, the best way to do that, will be to use `@DeleteDateColumn()`, as soft-delete is already inside typeorm.

```js
@Entity()
export class Child {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @DeleteDateColumn()
    deletedAt: Date;

    @ManyToOne(() => Parent, (parent) => parent.children)
    parent: Parent;
}
```

You can soft-remove your entity

```js
this.parentRepository.softRemove(child);
```

And you don't need any `where` clause.

```js
findAll(): Promise<Parent[]> {
    return this.parentRepository.find();
  }
```

To find with deleted

```js
this.parentRepository.find({ withDeleted: true });
```